# Distance Matrix quota

Tags: google-maps-api-3

For the standard use the quota is

> Users of the standard API:
>
> 2,500 free elements per day, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.
> Maximum of 25 origins or 25 destinations per request.
> 100 elements per request.
> 100 elements per second, calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side queries.

My request 1 origin with 2 destination, decrease 2 points of quota...
Is it normal ?

Any way to get time between this 3 point in 1 quota point ?

Thanks

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=43.51082,1.17594&destinations=43.51752814815077,1.1796296913585138|43.53063290640401,1.183816726190571&key=Mykey&traffic_model=best_guess&departure_time=now
```

Comment: The quota is based on the number of distances you get back.  It specifies that in the documentation.

Comment: where  ? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/usage-limits?hl=fr nothing related to "number of distances" here. Thanks

Comment: First paragraph: "limited by the number of allowed elements, where the number of origins times the number of destinations defines the number of elements." Combine that with your quote in your question.

Comment: just like @geocodezip said it's #origins*#destinations. 1 origin * 2 destinations = 2 points of quota